# Is it possible to count the amount of letters in the alphabet that exists in mysql column?

Tags: mysql

I would like to get a count of first letters in a column.

Example:
My column has names like  alice, jacob, james, britney and so on. I would like to count the amount of letters in the alphabet that exists. In the above it would be 3 even though the letter "j" is repeated.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(`name`, 1, 1)) FROM `users`
```